# I can't figure out the conditions of validation for presence of associated object at railsguide

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[This section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence) of railsguide says:

> If you want to be sure that an association is present, you'll need to test whether the associated object itself is present, and not the foreign key used to map the association.

What does `not the foreign key used to map the association.` mean?

At first I thought, if foreign_key option is set in the association, it wouldn't work. But it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means, if you want to validate actual association present (not only foreign key), you should have (assuming `belongs_to :user` association is present):

```
validates :user, presence: true
```

instead of:

```
validates :user_id, presence: true
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Marek. 
I understand thanks to your explanation.
It is very simple meaning.